# Converting vb.net to c# with Object

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following vb.net line:

```
Dim applesAs Object() = New Object([end] - startIndex - 1) {}
```

and [Developer Fusion's Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) converts it to this c# line:

```
object[] apples= new object[end - startIndex - 1];
```

The c# code seems to create an array of objects called apples, however I cannot find what the constructor for Object in vb is doing. Is it also creating an array? Am I wrong about what the c# line seems to be doing?

Comment: It's just predetermining the size of the object array. It's not a constructor it is an array initializer.

Comment: Your vb code looks as if it was translated from C# earlier ... (because that syntax is very unfamiliar for vb)

Comment: In C#, you use the size of the array, while in VB you use the upper bound, so the conversion should be: object[] apples = new object[end - startIndex];

Comment: @igrimpe:  what part doesn't look like VB?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Everything after and including the "=". Why wouldnt a VB guy simply write: Dim apples(maxindex) As Object ?

Comment: @igrimpe: yes, that's a good question, but the original is still perfectly fine VB code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the vb.net and c# code are creating an object array called apples.

- c# uses `[]` to indicate an array
- vb.net uses `()` to indicate an
  array

The parameters set the size of the array

```
new Object(5) 'vb.net
new object[6] //c#
```

Comment: In C#, that would be "new object[6]" since the VB code specifies the upper bound, not the size.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Thanks for that bit of info. I was not aware of that! I am new to vb.net.

Answer (score 7):

> however I cannot find what the constructor for Object in vb is doing.

Its not a constructor call,`()` are used in VB.Net for array indexing.

Also there is no constructor accepting a parameter with [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)